# Best way to handle multiple socket.io connections with mobile safari?

Tags: iphone, node.js, ipad, socket.io

I have created a node.js/socket.io/express site that has 2 screens, a lobby screen and a game screen. User's login and arrive in the lobby, where they can sit down and when someone sits down across from them a second browser window opens with the game in it. So two browser windows are open at once.

Things seem to work fine in desktop browsers, and the users stay connected to the lobby and the game screen, finish playing a game, and successfully return to the lobby afterwards.

However, in mobile safari (iPad, iPhone), I'm feeling pretty stuck! As soon as the game screen opens, and the lobby screen no longer has focus, it seems that the socket connection to the lobby instantly closes. Is there a way to prevent that from happening? Can I just set a really big timeout interval?Or is this just the way socket.io works with mobile safari? And if it's just the way it works, is there a best practice to achieve the equivalent of what I want to achieve instead?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not just reopen the connection when the other page is redisplayed?

Comment: There's a chat window in the lobby. In order to reopen the connection in the exact state it would be in if it hadn't been closed would required keeping a lot of (imo) unnecessary state on the server side. And, I would have to not remove people from the lobby if they disconnect from it and they happen to be connected to a game. In general, that whole way of solving the issue seems like a hack. Aren't sockets designed for this very purpose? To maintain a connection? If I have to store and manage state and all these disconnect/connect scenarios, what's the benefit of using sockets?

Comment: Sockets only remain active when the browser window is open. In Safari, it's not leaving the page in a state when it's not visible apparently that allows it to continue to use sockets.  Sockets are useful to push information to the client quickly and efficiently, without polling. Beyond that, they aren't much different from a traditional HTTP Ajax request. Given the often transient nature of network communcation, I wouldn't expect a consistent network connection. Further, if there's no activity, I wouldn't hold open a socket if not being used.